# How to get HttpContext.Current.User as custom principal in mvc c#

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I am trying to use the `HttpContext.Current.User` with my own class that inherits from `IPrincipal`. I am not exactly sure why..

```
var lIdentity = new UserIdentity(lFormsTicket);
var lRoles = lAuthUser.Roles.Select(x => x.Role.ToString()).ToArray();
var lPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(lIdentity, lRoles);

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User = lIdentity;
```

Right after I am setting this it works. But if I do another request on the site, it says that it cannot cast it. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `User` as `IIdentity` when it should be `IPrincipal`

```
var lIdentity = new UserIdentity(lFormsTicket);
var lRoles = lAuthUser.Roles.Select(x => x.Role.ToString()).ToArray();
var lPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(lIdentity, lRoles);

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User = lPrincipal;
```

You will probably need to use your own custom `IPrincipal`

```
public class UserPrincipal : IPrincipal {
    string[] roles;

    public UserPrincipal (IIdentity identity, param string[] roles) {
        this.Identity = identity;
        this.roles = roles ?? new string[]{ };
    }

    public IIdentity Identity { get; private set; }

    public bool IsInRole(string role) {
        return roles.Any(s => s == role);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if the application will complain as it may be expecting a `ClaimsPrincipal` derived type.

Comment: This isn't working either.

(BO.Security.UserIdentity)User.Identity results in the same problem.

Comment: Where is the error being thrown. Also show your `BO.Security.UserIdentity` class as we need to know what it inherits from. Note that `GenericPrincipal.Identity` => `Gets the System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity of the user represented by the current System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal`.

Comment: The error is being thrown everywhere I am trying to get the User.Identity as my custom useridentity except for the method where I am setting the user ( in the login ). UserIdentity inherits from IIdentity

Comment: `GenericPrincipal.Identity` returns a `GenericIdentity` regardless of the derived `IIdentity` you give it. It basically wraps whatever you give it in a `GenericIdentity` That is why when you try to cast it fails. You're going to have to create your own `IPrincipal` derived class.